# Как сузить окно FFT (быстрое преобразование Фурье)

Tags: fft, фурье

Ниже приложен код, который из массива чисел входного сигнала возвращает другой массив, где каждый элемент - это уровень сигнала на определенной частоте, так вот если подать сигнал допустим 1000 Гц с уровнем 1000000, то у всех других будет уровень от 100000 до 5000, даже у самых далеких, а хотелось бы 0, максимум у соседних элементов чтобы был только небольшой уровень сигнала. Читал про окна Ханна и другие, но так и не понял где в этом коде вообще окно, хотя по смыслу его нужно добавлять вот сюда "xre[i] = x[i];", но не получилось...

```
public class FourierTransform
{
    static private int n, nu;

    static private int BitReverse(int j)
    {
        int j2;
        int j1 = j;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= nu; i++)
        {
            j2 = j1 / 2;
            k = 2 * k + j1 - 2 * j2;
            j1 = j2;
        }
        return k;
    }

    static public double[] FFT(ref double[] x)
    {
        // Assume n is a power of 2
        n = x.Length;
        nu = (int)(Math.Log(n) / Math.Log(2));
        int n2 = n / 2;
        int nu1 = nu - 1;
        double[] xre = new double[n];
        double[] xim = new double[n];
        double[] magnitude = new double[n2];
        double[] decibel = new double[n2];
        double tr, ti, p, arg, c, s;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xre[i] = x[i];
            xim[i] = 0.0f;
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int l = 1; l <= nu; l++)
        {
            while (k < n)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
                {
                    p = BitReverse(k >> nu1);
                    arg = 2 * (double)Math.PI * p / n;
                    c = (double)Math.Cos(arg);
                    s = (double)Math.Sin(arg);
                    tr = xre[k + n2] * c + xim[k + n2] * s;
                    ti = xim[k + n2] * c - xre[k + n2] * s;
                    xre[k + n2] = xre[k] - tr;
                    xim[k + n2] = xim[k] - ti;
                    xre[k] += tr;
                    xim[k] += ti;
                    k++;
                }
                k += n2;
            }
            k = 0;
            nu1--;
            n2 = n2 / 2;
        }
        k = 0;
        int r;
        while (k < n)
        {
            r = BitReverse(k);
            if (r > k)
            {
                tr = xre[k];
                ti = xim[k];
                xre[k] = xre[r];
                xim[k] = xim[r];
                xre[r] = tr;
                xim[r] = ti;
            }
            k++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
            magnitude[i] = (float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i])));
            //decibel[i] = 10.0 * Math.Log10((float)(Math.Sqrt((xre[i] * xre[i]) + (xim[i] * xim[i]))));
        return magnitude;
        //return decibel;
    }
}
```

}

Пример входного сигнала приблизительно ~900 Гц, 512 выборок, значит выходной массив 256 получится:

```
double[] test = new double[]{-4901, -4818, -4657, -4419, -4111, -3737, -3302, -2814, -2276, -1698, -1092, -460, 160, 788, 1403, 1994, 2555, 3071, 3543, 3949, 4293, 4565, 4757, 4870, 4900, 4846, 4718, 4515, 4238, 3894, 3484, 3011, 2488, 1924, 1331, 709, 80, -539, -1171, -1779, -2349, -2887, -3377, -3810, -4181, -4482, -4700, -4844, -4904, -4884, -4796, -4630, -4381, -4058, -3670, -3213, -2705, -2149, -1564, -943, -304, 316, 954, 1566, 2158, 2715, 3226, 3683, 4076, 4397, 4646, 4816, 4916, 4936, 4873, 4730, 4501, 4199, 3824, 3384, 2888, 2343, 1763, 1152, 522, -114, -751, -1378, -1982, -2552, -3079, -3555, -3964, -4309, -4586, -4790, -4919, -4966, -4928, -4803, -4596, -4313, -3959, -3539, -3053, -2526, -1955, -1354, -727, -91, 551, 1180, 1790, 2373, 2908, 3397, 3831, 4201, 4509, 4741, 4894, 4964, 4949, 4852, 4671, 4411, 4073, 3674, 3217, 2698, 2146, 1556, 939, 300, -333, -967, -1597, -2182, -2732, -3241, -3699, -4098, -4430, -4686, -4862, -4953, -4966, -4888, -4731, -4494, -4182, -3805, -3370, -2882, -2338, -1752, -1137, -491, 134, 765, 1394, 1988, 2560, 3084, 3563, 3979, 4333, 4614, 4811, 4927, 4961, 4910, 4775, 4568, 4283, 3937, 3523, 3040, 2514, 1942, 1337, 712, 74, -558, -1185, -1804, -2381, -2923, -3416, -3851, -4226, -4524, -4745, -4888, -4943, -4918, -4816, -4638, -4389, -4062, -3667, -3206, -2692, -2128, -1533, -923, -293, 355, 989, 1603, 2193, 2748, 3257, 3710, 4101, 4419, 4662, 4830, 4914, 4922, 4854, 4707, 4476, 4172, 3795, 3353, 2856, 2312, 1730, 1119, 486, -141, -767, -1405, -2005, -2566, -3093, -3561, -3969, -4308, -4574, -4772, -4890, -4933, -4892, -4764, -4561, -4282, -3923, -3501, -3021, -2491, -1924, -1320, -702, -69, 567, 1191, 1801, 2376, 2910, 3395, 3824, 4183, 4483, 4711, 4861, 4930, 4913, 4814, 4633, 4372, 4040, 3640, 3179, 2672, 2115, 1529, 921, 285, -345, -973, -1598, -2179, -2729, -3230, -3677, -4066, -4393, -4647, -4822, -4915, -4929, -4855, -4694, -4460, -4152, -3776, -3334, -2849, -2312, -1732, -1127, -496, 134, 766, 1388, 1978, 2533, 3059, 3531, 3942, 4293, 4569, 4772, 4889, 4927, 4877, 4746, 4539, 4254, 3903, 3491, 3021, 2496, 1933, 1336, 716, 80, -549, -1170, -1779, -2355, -2893, -3383, -3818, -4188, -4487, -4712, -4857, -4919, -4896, -4791, -4612, -4361, -4038, -3647, -3196, -2688, -2130, -1537, -930, -304, 337, 965, 1579, 2166, 2718, 3225, 3679, 4071, 4395, 4638, 4807, 4893, 4896, 4827, 4683, 4458, 4160, 3790, 3354, 2859, 2317, 1741, 1131, 503, -127, -759, -1377, -1973, -2539, -3060, -3534, -3945, -4286, -4560, -4750, -4867, -4909, -4871, -4752, -4552, -4275, -3922, -3503, -3030, -2505, -1934, -1337, -720, -93, 547, 1174, 1780, 2355, 2890, 3377, 3810, 4173, 4465, 4691, 4841, 4910, 4903, 4811, 4633, 4376, 4048, 3651, 3189, 2680, 2127, 1538, 929, 301, -347, -975, -1578, -2173, -2720, -3220, -3667, -4056, -4378, -4634, -4816, -4913, -4922, -4853, -4702, -4470, -4162, -3783, -3344, -2848, -2314, -1738, -1132, -514, 127, 764, 1382, 1979, 2542, 3055, 3526, 3940, 4291, 4571, 4771, 4892, 4932, 4885, 4755, 4547, 4259, 3905, 3493, 3020, 2499, 1934, 1332, 713, 75, -565, -1184, -1783, -2353, -2892, -3381, -3819, -4191, -4492, -4719, -4864, -4923, -4899, -4796, -4609, -4353, -4031, -3636, -3184, -2679, -2120, -1532, -909, -276, 348, 976, 1586, 2174, 2727, 3233, 3684, 4074, 4400, 4645, 4812, 4901, 4903};
```

Пример для запуска и вывода:

```
        double[] magn = FastFourierTransform.FFT(ref test);

        foreach (double m in magn)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже код FFT какой-то неправильный, нашел другие примеры и библиотеки, с ними всё нормально и окна работают разные, сразу видно результат, код не выкладываю, еще не определился какой мне больше подходит. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

какова длительность вашего сигнала? 512 выборок на каком интервале времени? при спектральном анализе верхняя частота спектра зависит от частоты дискретизации, которая должна быть не менее, чем в 2 раза больше верхней частоты спектра анализируемого сигнала. Тип окна, будь то окно Ханна, Блэкмена, Хэмминга или другое никак не поможет вам сузить спектр, окна используются для уменьшения дисперсии спектральной оценки и для уменьшения растекания спектра. А вообще идея использовать окно весьма здравая. Для этого вам надо умножить каждый отчёт входного сигнала на соответствующий весовой коэффициент окна.

Comment: Длительность бесконечная для теста, сэмплов в секунду 44100, байт на фрейм 2048, бит на сэмпл 16, каналов 2, но в примере один левый.
Мне не спектр нужно сузить, а как раз растекание спектра уменьшить, хотелось бы в 0 уменьшить боковые лепестки, я не знаю реально ли это, хотя бы дальние, чтобы только соседние плавно перетекали в 0.

Comment: В общем, чем реще уменьшаться боковые лепестки относительно входной частоты, тем лучше, в идеале, только входная частота должна иметь положительный уровень сигнала, а остальные 0.

Comment: Следовательно, верхняя частота спектра порядка 22 кГц. Вы подаёте входной синусоидальный сигнал 1 кГц и у вас анализ спектра показывает наличие гармоник этого сигнала в широкой полосе частот вплоть до 22 кГц. И эти гармоники, как я понимаю, подавлены относительно основной гармоники в 10-200 раз. Это вполне приличный результат, если учесть что реальный входной сигнал у вас наверняка не чисто синусоидальный. Можете уменьшить частоту дискретизации и у вас будет более узкий спектр.

Comment: и я не до конца понимаю вашу задачу. спектральный анализ позволяет определить спектральный состав анализируемого сигнала. если у вас в спектре обнаруживаются большие уровни частот, которых там быть не должно, то это вопрос больше к чистоте входного сигнала, а не к методу анализа.

Comment: использование окна конечно поможет сгладить спектр, вам надо только рассчитать коэффициенты окна, так чтобы число коэффициентов (длина окна) было равно числу отсчётов анализируемого сигнала. И умножить каждый отсчёт сигнала на свой коэффициент.

Comment: Да я просто цветомузыку делаю, и эти побочные моргания мешают, я пробовал другой код с окном Блэкмена, по-лучше, но всё равно не идеально, на bass.dll с тем же сигналом такого нет, всё чисто, "выпирает" только нужная частота и плавно затухает рядом, а не в конце 20кГц, но алгоритм неизвестен...

Я не знаю куда коэффициенты добавлять, чтобы поиграться с ними... Пробовал в разные места, но не получилось, то исключения то вообще нет сигналов...